# Angular unable to recognize my controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a project where homeapp.js contains the angular.module dependencies:

```
var HomeApp = angular.module('HomeApp', [
                'ngRoute',
                'ngCookies',
                    'HomeControllers',
                    'metadataControllers',
                    'MyControllers',
                    'ScheduleControllers'
                ]);

HomeApp.config(['$routeProvider',
                function($routeProvider) {
                  $routeProvider.
                    when('/schedules', {
                        templateUrl: 'pages/list_schedule.html',
                        controller: 'ScheduleControllers'
                    });
```

and in a ScheduleController.js, I have:

```
angular.module('ScheduleControllers', []).controller('PhoneListCrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.phones = [
        {'name': 'Nexus S',
        'snippet': 'Fast just got faster with Nexus S.'},
        {'name': 'Motorola XOOM with Wi-Fi',
        'snippet': 'The Next, Next Generation tablet.'},
        {'name': 'MOTOROLA XOOM',
        'snippet': 'The Next, Next Generation tablet.'}
    ];
});
```

this is basically the code snippet from the angular tutorial.

In the index.html, I have:

```
<html lang="en-CA" ng-app="HomeApp">
...
<li id="id_schedule_list" class="header_list"><a href="#schedules" class="link_without_underline">List Schedule</a></li>
...
```

which then directs to this the schedules.html with only the follow codes:

```
<div>
    <div ng-controller="PhoneListCrl">
        <p>{{phones}}</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

However when the html is opened from browser, it shows {{phones}} straight, without being able to show the full json object. The console says

```
https://docs.angularjs.org/error/ng/areq?p0=ScheduleControllers&p1=not%20a 1.#QNAN0unction%2C%20got%20undefined
```

Which doesn't really make sense to me, but I guess it is saying ScheduleControllers is undefined.

## EDIT:

In angluar's tutorial, the app.js says:

```
var phonecatApp = angular.module('phonecatApp', [
'ngRoute',
'phonecatAnimations',
'phonecatControllers',
'phonecatFilters',
'phonecatServices'
]);
```

and then in controllers.js, it has:

```
var phonecatControllers = angular.module('phonecatControllers', []);
phonecatControllers.controller('PhoneListCtrl', ['$scope', 'Phone',
function($scope, Phone) {
$scope.phones = Phone.query();
$scope.orderProp = 'age';
}]);
```

Looks like I am almost doing exactly what the tutorial does, but why it doesn't work for me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is actually with the route.  You are using the module's name for the controller instead of the actual controller name.

Where you have `controller: 'ScheduleControllers'`, you instead need `controller: 'PhoneListCtrl'`.  Additionally, the code you pasted has a typo in the controller definition.  You need a t in PhoneListCtrl in

```
angular.module('ScheduleControllers', []).controller('PhoneListCtrl',     function($scope) `
```

**EDIT**

In the following code, you are telling angular which controller to load when you access the /schedules route.  Right now, it is pointing to 'ScheduleControllers', which is a module, not a controller.  Change it to match the second block and you should be good to go.

```
HomeApp.config(['$routeProvider',
            function($routeProvider) {
              $routeProvider.
                when('/schedules', {
                    templateUrl: 'pages/list_schedule.html',
                    controller: 'ScheduleControllers'
                });

HomeApp.config(['$routeProvider',
            function($routeProvider) {
              $routeProvider.
                when('/schedules', {
                    templateUrl: 'pages/list_schedule.html',
                    controller: 'PhoneListCtrl'
                });
```

See https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_07 for reference.

Comment: The parts you copied from the tutorial don't cover the route registration, which is where you problem lies.  Your controller and dependency loading are correct, you just need to modify your route registration.  I'll edit my response above to be more explicit.

Answer (score 2):

You're attaching your controller to another Angular module:

```
// This line creates a new module named "ScheduleControllers"
// And attaches the "PhoneListCrl" to it.
angular.module('ScheduleControllers', []).controller('PhoneListCrl', function() { ... });
```

If you want it to be visible to your `HomeApp` then attach it to that module:

```
// You need to attach "PhoneListCrl" to your original module.
angular.module('HomeApp').controller('PhoneListCrl', function() { ... });
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. I have edited the OP. Im not sure what goes wrong when I am trying to follow the Angular tutorial...

Answer (score 1):

the `controller: 'ScheduleControllers'` is name of module and not controller, hence the issue